How to write a ByteArray to an Excel file and saving it in external storage?
I want to write ByteArray data which is coming from Retrofit API (ResponseBody as return type from API) into Excel file and store into external memory of android SD Card.
try {
    var path = mContext?.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)

    val stream = FileOutputStream(path.toString() + "/ExcelTest.xlsx")
    stream.write(it.data?.bytes())//it.data->retrofit ResponseBody that am convert to ByteArray
    stream.flush()
    stream.close()


    //To open the Excel file
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
        setDataAndType(
            Uri.fromFile(path),
            "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
        )
        flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
    }
    mContext?.startActivity(intent)
} catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {

}

This is my suspend function:
@GET("URL")
@Streaming
suspend fun getDownloadFile(): ResponseBody

Output:
When I run the app, its creating Excel file with empty data(0KB) in it. and when I tried opened the created file its showing this popup alert:

Excel cannot open the file ’ExcelTest.xlsx’ because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.


In my opinion you are trying to test too much at once. You have three actions you need TK verify individually to understand the problem: 1. Test if the retrofit API is really returning the data you expect (download it manually and check  the content). 2. Test your download code if it is really capable of writing the retrieved data to a file and 3. if the used cod for opening the saved file as Excel file in a different app works. I strongly recommend to test each action individually instead of all together.

@Robert After i converted Retrofit Response to byte-array am getting like this "[B@3ee1260"

Please stop using byte[].toString(). In Java/Kotlin this had never and will never print anything useful. Convert it to hexadecimal or base64 representation and print that.
